# raspberry pi 3 カーネルクロスコンパイルについて

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, kernel

## 今できてること

raspberry pi 3B にubuntu 23.04を入れています。　libbpfを使いために、CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTFを設定したカーネルを、wsl上のubuntuでクロスコンパイルを行うところまではできました。

参考にしたサイト様は以下の2つです。
[Raspberry Pi Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html)
[Raspberry Pi OSのカーネルソースビルド手順解説](https://aquarius-train.hatenablog.com/entry/Raspberry_Pi_OS%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8D%E3%83%AB%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%83%93%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E6%89%8B%E9%A0%86%E8%A7%A3%E8%AA%AC)

## 試した方法

[1](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html)の方では、SDカードにコピーする方法を試しました。　が、うまくマウントされているのかわからずコピーもうまくできていないようでした。これは私の知識と経験不足です。

[1](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html)に、config.txtの中のkernel=を変更して起動すると良いと書かれていましたが、/boot配下に、[Raspberry Piカーネルクロスコンパイル環境の構築](https://tomosoft.jp/design/?p=5257)のようにscpを使ってImageを置いて、指定したのですが、起動しませんでした、、、

[2](https://aquarius-train.hatenablog.com/entry/Raspberry_Pi_OS%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%8D%E3%83%AB%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B9%E3%83%93%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E6%89%8B%E9%A0%86%E8%A7%A3%E8%AA%AC)の方法ですと、scpをした後、/libを/配下にコピーしようと思っても出来ませんでした。

## 知りたいこと

クロスコンパイルできているカーネルを、どのようにしてSDカードに入れて起動させることができるのでしょうか？

詳しいやり方など教えていただけたら幸いです。

Comment: 参考にされているサイト（特にふたつ目の方）は Raspberry Pi OS 用のものですが、入れたいものは Ubuntu という理解でよいですか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu そうです。　参考にしただけです。

Comment: 質問のタイトルと今問題になっていることが微妙に合っていないような気がします。この辺の記事を元に、先ずはカスタム作成したものでは無く既に公開・配布されているRaspberry Pi 3用Ubuntuで起動できることを確認してみてはどうでしょう？ [Raspberry Pi で動く様々なOS一覧まとめ13種類！](https://raspida.com/support-os-rspi), [Raspberry Pi Imagerによるラズパイ起動用microSDの作成](https://www.openaudiolab.com/rpi-imager/jp/), [Raspberry Pi OSのインストール – 公式Imager対応](https://www.indoorcorgielec.com/resources/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-os%E3%81%AE%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB/), [【2023年最新版】OSインストールから初期設定まで｜セットアップ手順のすべて](https://sozorablog.com/raspberrypi_initial_setting/)

Comment: @kunif ありがとうございます。
Raspberry pi Imagerを使って、ubuntu23の起動は確認しています。

Comment: クロスコンパイルしているのは、ラズパイ用のカーネルになってます、

Comment: そうだとすれば今度はカスタマイズしたカーネルをクロスではなくx86_32/64機やRaspberry PiではないRAM/Storageの豊富なARM機向けにコンパイルして、そうしたマシンで動作を確認してみるとかしてみたのでしょうか？ そうしたことも含めて質問に追記すれば助言・回答出来る人が出てくるかもしれませんね。

Comment: @kunif 
ありがとうございます。
RAM/Storageの豊富なARM機が無いので、x86_32/64機向けにコンパイルしたいと思います。

ただ、カーネルが変わってくるのでラズパイ用のカーネルをx86_32/64機にするというわけではなく、他のカーネルで同様の設定を行い、動かしてみるということであっていますか？

Comment: はい、そうです。色々と状況を変えて元々の変更が有効なのかどうか確かめてみる感じですね。

Comment: @kunif  わかりました。
ありがとうございます。

Comment: [このディスカッションをチャットで続行](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148897/discussion-between-lapis-and-kunif)しましょう。